# distance tree to obtain an initial assessment of the population structure

Tags: r

I don't understand what the error message is showing, what I have to do here.

```
cols <- brewer.pal(n = nPop(genlight.smelt), name = "Dark2")
```

> Warning message:
> In brewer.pal(n = nPop(genlight.smelt), name = "Dark2") :
> minimal value for n is 3, returning requested palette with 3 different levels

Comment: What does `nPop(genlight.smelt)` return? Is it at least three? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: #convert data from vcf object to genlight
all(colnames(smelt.VCF@gt)[-1] == pop.data$AccessID)
genlight.smelt <- vcfR2genlight(smelt.VCF)
pop(genlight.smelt) <- pop.data$PopType
genlight.smelt

#create a pairwise genetic distance matrix for individuals or populations

tree <- aboot(genlight.smelt, tree = "upgma", distance = bitwise.dist, sample = 100, showtree = F, cutoff = 0, quiet = T)
cols <- brewer.pal(n = nPop(genlight.smelt), name = "Dark2"
Here, I have 5 population types, but in my tree it shows 3 colrs for 3 poptypes, don't understand how to fix that code!

Comment: problem solved. Many thanks!